# WebStorm 8: Grunt Compass fails claiming Ruby & Compass not in PATH

Tags: javascript, ruby, gruntjs, webstorm, compass-sass

[image: Grunt Console]

[image: Warning: Running "compass:dist" (compass) task Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work.]

The new Grunt Console is a welcome breath of fresh js workflow in JetBrains WebStorm 8.  This is a blocker that's preventing me from truly developing with pleasure ;)

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10.

I attempted a fix by adding Ruby and Compass from my default rvm to the system, `PATH=/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby` and `/home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/compass` (appended to /etc/profile) to no avail.

Also I've added `PATH=/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH`, no help.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Does Grunt work when being run not from WebStorm? Do you run WebStorm from a terminal, or from Desktop?

Comment: Yes in fact, runs perfectly from Ubuntu Terminal, And (the real stumper) also runs perfectly from the "Terminal" console within WebStorm!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Grunt myself ... but can you print the `PATH` from grunt task? Compare that with what you see in terminal -- most likely it will be different. Also -- try launching WebStorm from terminal and not via launcher icon -- will it work properly this way?

Comment: nickckaye, did this ever get solved? I'm having this exact problem and it's driving me bonkers

Comment: @ElRudi personally I've elected to use LESS exclusively in my Node.js-based projects. That said, I use SASS all day in Ruby/Rails.

Comment: @ElRudi that said, have you tried using RVM, adding a `.ruby-version` and `Gemfile` with `compass` installed, and then running your Grunt "in the bundle context" a.k.a. `bundle exec compass`

Comment: I tried to just use a file watcher for the scss instead of grunt, and even that doesn't work. If I use `/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/bin/scss --no-cache --update custom.scss:custom.css` from the command line, all works fine, but the file watcher in webstorm that I've configured to use that same path says `Could not find 'sass' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)`

I _am_ using RVM, but I'm new to it. I'm not quite sure how to apply your advice; could you elaborate? Same goes for grunt advice! Thanks...!

Answer (score 2):

I know you mentioned you are running Ubuntu - but hopefully this helps point some people in the right direction when they arrive at this answer.

I was able to resolve this issue for Windows by opening WebStorm and editing:

```
Settings > Terminal > Shell path
```

and simply adding the extension to enable ruby to the cmd prompt:

```
cmd.exe /E:ON /K C:\Ruby193\bin\setrbvars.bat
```